# forEach is not a function Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm receiving this error even though this.toilets is full of objects

[image]

The log shows firstly this.location, then this.toilets which is full of objects as displayed.

```
this.loadHomeData().then(data => {
                this.toilets = data;
                console.log(this.toilets);

            });
```

---

```
loadHomeData() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get('http://url-to-my-server/' + this.location.coords.latitude + '/' + this.location.coords.longitude)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.data = data;
                    resolve(this.data);
                });
        });
    }
```

---

```
this.toilets.forEach((toilet) => {
                console.log(toilet);
           });
```

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Added for you Günter

Comment: it is an object containing key value pairs and not an array [].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

forEach is working with array and not an object.

You would need to get keys and then iterate

```
Object.keys(this.toilets).forEach(key=> {
    console.log(this.toilets[key])  ;     
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this.toilets is a object containing objects .forEach() might not work.
Instead you can use :

```
for(var i in this.toilets){
    console.log(this.toilets[i]);//This will print the objects
    console.log(i);//This will print the index of the objects
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use .do operator for this

```
loadHomeData() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get('http://url-to-my-server/' + this.location.coords.latitude + '/' + this.location.coords.longitude)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .do(res => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(res)))
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.data = data;
                    resolve(this.data);
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: what you did inside `do`? and how can this change will help OP to fix his problem?

Comment: 'do' does not exist on type Observable<any>

Comment: @JoshuaNissenbaum did you import the do operator?

Comment: @PankajParkar if OP is looking a way to log the data may be this would be helpful.

Comment: How can this fix the problem anyway? Looks like it prints but doesn't change the data. Printing the data is just for testing purposes

Comment: @Aravind please read question what OP needs, and then answer it accordingly... `do` operator would not help here, it would just help to do intermediate task, while performing operations in stream.